# how to get the second y axis to start at the same 0 as the first y axis

Tags: excel, charts

[image]

I want the lines to start at the same 0 y origin as the first y axis NPS bar charts. it looks silly this way right now and I can't figure out how to do this. Thanks for your help

Comment: The chart is in the link i forgot to name, whoops!

Answer (score 0):

1) Select the right-hand axis

2) right-click on it and select `Format Axis...` from the drop down menu.

3) Under "Axis Options" give matching bounds for the right-hand axis to the left-hand one (in your case I believe the minimum should be `-160` and the maximum should be `800`)

Comment: Thanks! i didn't think about bumping it up by putting a negative lower value in. worked great